# How to gain insights in text classifications with error analysis?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, text-classification, countvectorizer

I'm doing text classification for dialect. And I'm using naive bayes classifier with countVectorizer. I'm having many misclassified texts. Is there a method to analyse those errors to figure out where the classification is going wrong? For example, if I could know what words are being used to misclassify text as A, while it should be classified as B and then I can take those out words from the corpus of A.

Should switch to unsupervised learning using clustering? or neural networks and deep learning? if naive bayes classifier isn't working.

Also, how can I know how countVectorizer classified the documents? And which words he used to classify a document.

Comment: Analyzing errors depends on many things. You need to check what kind text cleaning you are doing, what stopwords you are removing, whether stemming or lemmatization is needed or not, etc. It is not that straight forward. You can also use tfidf vectorizer. You can create a list of records which were wrongly classified and check the most frequent words which were wrongly classified.

Comment: How can I check the most frequent words that were wrongly classified?

Comment: append as a string all the reviews which are wrongly classified, then use the `Counter` package [link](https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-counter/)

Comment: Try [shap](https://github.com/slundberg/shap)